# Rally SDK 2.0 displaying debug information

Tags: rally

I can get simple queries working and displaying using the new 2.0 framework, I want to display some debug type information back to the screen but I am finding the Rally default app is overlaying everything.

App is based on standard i.e.

```
Ext.define('ReleaseHistory', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    grid: null,
etc...
```

What is the best way for me to 'dump' information back to the screen using this framework, lets say I have an array of stuff, in the old SDK I can do something like this:

```
var results = JSON.stringify(dataAddedOrRemoved); 
dojo.byId("debug").innerHTML = results;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the easiest way to inspect code or data in an app is through the developer tools provided by your browser.  console.log statements can also be useful.

Otherwise, you will probably find the following guide helpful:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/add_content

SDK2 is built on top of ExtJS and everything is a component or a container.  You will have a bad time directly modifying the DOM without the framework's knowledge.  Here is a simple example of how to just add some arbitrary html content to your app body:

```
this.add({
    xtype: 'component',
    html: 'content-goes-here'
});
```